# Any Parameters in Methods in ASP.NET MVC (Linux) cause System.TypeLoadException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, monodevelop

IDE: MonoDevelop: 5.7 
ASP.NET MVC: 5.2 
OS: Linux (Mint 17)

When I include any parameter as part of any method in my HelloWorldController and navigate to that methods respective URL I get "System.TypeLoadException" Error. Removing the parameter from the method resolves the error. I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to find solutions through searches and IRC channels, and the most common solution I've found unfortunately is switching to Visual Studio. I apologize if this isn't a properly structured 'programming question', but I'm at my wits end and hoping for help :) Thanks.

Is there a way to resolve this error?

```
// HelloWorldController.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace test.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /HelloWorld/
        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my <b>default</b> action...";
        }

        //
        // GET:/HelloWorld/Welcome/
        public string Welcome(string name)
        {
            name = "Joe";
            int age = 22;
            return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello " + name + " age: " + age);
        }   
    }
}
```

Error Message with stack trace:

System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.
Exception stack trace:
at System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider () [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19 (System.AsyncCallback asyncCallback, System.Object asyncState) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504228/mono-3-system-web-exception-on-file-post) will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, that's one of the many solutions I'd already attempted without success.